# Pytorch Transformer: Embed dimension (d_model) is same dimension as src embedding but is also total dimension of model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp

I have been trying to use torch.nn.Transformer. I am confused about the embed_dim (aka d_model). If I have an input of size (10, 7) where 7 is my embedding dimension and 10 is my sequence length, does d_model = 7? The MHA component says https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html

> embed_dim – Total dimension of the model.
> num_heads – Number of parallel attention heads. Note that embed_dim
> will be split across num_heads (i.e. each head will have dimension
> embed_dim // num_heads).

How can embed_dim be both num_heads * dim_per_head and also the embedding size of each token? This doesn't make sense. In other words, why do none of these code versions work?

`x = nn.Transformer(nhead=2, d_model=7)` leads to

> AssertionError: embed_dim must be divisible by num_heads

```
x = nn.Transformer(nhead=2, d_model=14)
a = torch.rand((10,7))
x(a,a)
```

leads to

> RuntimeError: the feature number of src and tgt must be equal to
> d_model

Answer (score 3):

> If I have an input of size (10, 7) where 7 is my embedding dimension and 10 is my sequence length, does d_model = 7?

Yes, since d_model is the number of expected features into the model ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html))

> How can embed_dim be both num_heads * dim_per_head and also the embedding size of each token? This doesn't make sense. In other words, why do none of these code versions work?

If you look at the documentation you [linked](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) earlier, you can see that the Multihead Attention is calculated by concatenating the output of each head. Therefore, even though each head will have `embed_dim/num_heads` dimensions, the embedding size of each token will still end up being `embed_dim`, since we are then concatenating `num_heads` heads into our MHA calculation.

> In other words, why do none of these code versions work?
>
> `x = nn.Transformer(nhead=2, d_model=7)`

Since `embed_dim` is split across multiple heads, then it follows that you cannot have 2 heads but with 7 dims overall. This would either mean that each head embeds 3.5 dims, which cannot work, or that the heads embed in a different number of dimensions, which wouldn't make sense.

> ```
> x = nn.Transformer(nhead=2, d_model=14)
> a = torch.rand((10,7))
> x(a,a)
> ```

The second error comes from the fact that you are telling the model to expect an input dimension of 14, but then feed it a model with input dimension of 7. If you tried

```
transformer_model = nn.Transformer(nhead=2, d_model=14)
model_input = torch.rand((10,14)) # Note the number of dims here now matches d_model
output = torch.rand((10,14))
transformer_model(model_input,output)
# Or you can run on the MHA class
MHA_layer = nn.MultiheadAttention(num_heads=7, embed_dim=14, kdim=4, vdim=4)
k = torch.rand((10, 4))
v = torch.rand((10, 4))
MHA_layer(model_input,k,v)
```

there would be no problem. You can see in the MultiheadedAttention forward docs that query embedding dimension is embed_dim. The key and value dimensions are the same as `embed_dim` unless explicitly defined.

Comment: Is d_model the embedding before or after the linear transformation of the input to W,Q,V?

Comment: @JobHunter69 It's the embedding dimension of your input, which needed for the encoder and decoder models in `nn.Transformer`

Comment: My confusion came from the fact that the input embedding is the exact same size as the post linear transform embedding.